# Consuming https enabled asp.net web site opens multiple connection with multiple ports

Tags: web-server, iis-7.5, website

maybe this question is a stupid one, if so be patient, now at the time of the question I have no time to really investigate the "issue".

I have an IIS 7.5 asp.net web site that is going in production, I saw that when an user connect from an ip, that connection is spawned across multiple connections on a progressive range of ports, for example:

```
   Local Address    Foreign Address
```

- 150.xx.xxx.xxx:443 - 80.xx.xxx.60:24565
- 150.xx.xxx.xxx:443 - 80.xx.xxx.60:24570
- 150.xx.xxx.xxx:443 - 80.xx.xxx.60:24572
- 150.xx.xxx.xxx:443 - 80.xx.xxx.60:24573
- 150.xx.xxx.xxx:443 - 80.xx.xxx.60:24575
- 150.xx.xxx.xxx:443 - 80.xx.xxx.60:24580

The site is hosted in an "application" inside an IIS web site.
Any idea?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Most web browers are multi-threaded and will open up several connections to pipeline data efficiently, while one finishes reading the HTML content, another one will get the JS libraries, another one will get the pictures, etc.  Are you actually seeing problems?